# Variables incrementales por línea

Tags: php, variables

Buenas nuevamente @azeós, al hilo de lo que pregunté antes... Cómo puedo guardar en alguna variable los precios que salen en cada línea, no sé si me explico:
en esta línea:  `<td><?php $precioinicial[$i] = $c["q"]*$r->price;` está el total de cada línea y es el que quiero que me guarde en diferentes variables globales para después procesarlas y poder usarlas en otro php

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
 <th>Cantidad</th>
 <th>Producto</th>
 <th>Precio Unitario</th>
 <th>Total</th>
 <th></th>
</thead>
<?php 
/*
* Apartir de aqui hacemos el recorrido de los productos obtenidos y los reflejamos en una tabla.
*/


foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $i => $c):
$products = $con->query("select * from product where id=$c[product_id]");
$r = $products->fetch_object();
 ?>
<tr>
<th><?php echo $c["q"];?></th>
 <td><?php echo $r->name;?></td>
 <td><?php echo $r->price; ?> € </td>
 <td><?php $precioinicial[$i] = $c["q"]*$r->price; //éste es el total de cada línea y es el que quiero que me guarde en diferentes variables globales para después procesarlas y poder usarlas en otro php
 echo $precioinicial[$i];?> € </td>
 
 
 
 <td style="width:260px;">
 <?php
 $found = false;
 foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $c) { if($c["product_id"]==$r->id){ $found=true; break; }}
 ?>
  <a href="php/delfromcart.php?id=<?php echo $c["product_id"];?>" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
 </td>
 </tr>

<?php endforeach;?>
 <tr>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
 Total sin IVA<br>
 <?php 
 
 $_SESSION["preciototal"] = array_sum($precioinicial);
 
 echo $_SESSION["preciototal"];
 ?> € 
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Talvez puedas probar en crear un `array` vacio y lo insertar dentro de tu bucle, para que guarde el valor cada vez que se ejecute

Comment: Te sugeriría enviarlas por post mediante ajax No sé si entendí bien tu requerimiento pero eso de las variables globales para acceder desde otro formulario no está bien, Si son "n" precios tendrías "n" variables de sesión que en tal caso de que lo logres, tendrías que recorrer estas variables en el otro .php Es mucho procesamiento y para el manteniemento es terrible.

Comment: Otra alternativa es crear un "<div id="proceso_auxiliar"></div>" y luego cuando le des click al botón capturas el evento para que ejecute el archivo .php (lo cargas con el evento .load) ese que necesitas que reciba las variables  y entonces procesas o haces lo que debas hacer dentro de ese div. Es sólo una sugerencia

Comment: Nada chicos!!!!! No me acordé que yo el precio unitario lo tengo almacenado en BBDD, con lo que sólo tuve que hacer para mostrarlo en el envío del pedido lo siguiente:
`--Precio: " . $row["q"]*$row["price"] . "\n";`

Y así queda solucionado por línea.

Muchísimas gracias a todos.....